# DART: syntax of future then

Tags: dart, dart-async

I don´t understand the syntax of the `then()` clause.

**1.** `myFuture(6).then( (erg) => print(erg) )`

What´s `(erg) => expr` syntactically?

I thougt it could be a function, but

```
then( callHandler2(erg)
```

doesn´t work, Error:

```
"Multiple markers at this line
- The argument type 'void' cannot be assigned to the parameter type '(String) -> 
 dynamic'
- Undefined name 'erg'
- Expected to find ')'"
```

**2.** `myFuture(5).then( (erg) { callHandler(erg);}, 
                    onError: (e) => print (e)`

```
What´s `onError: (e) => expr"` syntactically?
```

**3.** Is there a difference between the `onError:` and the `.catchError(e)` variants?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1) The *Fat Arrow* is syntactic sugar for short anonymous functions. The two functions below are the same:

```dart
someFuture(arg).then((erg) => print(erg));
// is the same as
someFuture(arg).then((erg) { return print(erg); });
```

Basically the fat arrow basically automatically returns the evaluation of the next expression.

If your `callHandler2` has the correct signature, you can just pass the function name. The signature being that it accept the number of parameters as the future will pass to the `then` clause, and returns null/void.

For instance the following will work:

```dart
void callHandler2(someArg) { ... }
// .. elsewhere in the code
someFuture(arg).then(callHandler);
```

2) See answer 1). The *fat arrow* is just syntactic sugar equivalent to:

```dart
myFuture(5).then( (erg){ callHandler(erg);}, onError: (e){ print(e); });
```

3) `catchError` allows you to chain the error handling after a series of futures. First its important to understand that `then` calls can be chained, so a `then` call which returns a  `Future` can be chained to another `then` call. The `catchError` will catch errors both synchronous and asynchronous from all `Future`s in the chain. Passing an `onError` argument will only deal with an error in the `Future` its an argument for and for any synchronous code in your `then` block. Any asynchronous code in your `then` block will remain uncaught.

Recent tendency in most Dart code is to use `catchError` and omit the `onError` argument.

Comment: tnx, answered all my questions, in (1) I first tried .then(callHandler(erg)) with a parameter, which failed.

Answer (score 10):

I will attempt to elaborate more on Matt's answer, hopefully to give more insights.

What `then()` requires is a function (callback), whose signature matches the future's type.

For example, given a `Future<String> myFuture` and `doSomething` being any function that accepts a `String` input, you can call `myFuture.then(doSomething)`. Now, there are several ways to define a function that takes a `String` in Dart:

```
Function(String) doSomething1 = (str) => /* do something with str */  // only one command
Function(String) doSomething2 = (str) { /* do something with str */ } // several commands
Function(String) doSomething3 = myFunction;
myFunction(String) { // Dart will auto imply return type here
  /* do something with str */ // several commands
}
```

Any of those 3 function definitions (the right hand side of `=`) could go inside `then()`. The first two definitions are called **lambda functions**, they are created at runtime and cannot be reused unless you manually copy the code. Lambda functions can potentially yield language-like expressions, i.e. `(connection) => connection.connect()`. The third approach allows the function to be reused. Lambda functions are common in many languages, you can read more about it here: https://medium.com/@chineketobenna/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-functions-in-javascript-3aa760c958ae.

The reason why you can't put `callHandler2(erg)` inside `then()` is because `callHandler2(erg)` uses an undefined variable `erg`. Using the lambda function, you will be able to tell `then()` that the `erg` in `callHandler2(erg)` is the output of the future, so it knows where to get `erg` value.