# The Fat Arrow is syntactic sugar - but do not return

Tags: dart

The Fat Arrow is syntactic sugar, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860863/dart-syntax-of-future-then)

But if I remove return in(look for: `future.then(print); // << Removed return`) then it complains about missing return?:

Hmm, or am I missing a "return-return" kind og thing...

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  printsome();
  print("After should be called first...");
}

Future<void> printsome() {
  final future = delayedFunction();
  future.then(print); // << Removed return
  // You don't *have* to return the future here.
  // But if you don't, callers can't await it.
}

const news = '<gathered news goes here>';
const oneSecond = Duration(seconds: 1);
Future<String> delayedFunction() =>
    Future.delayed(oneSecond, () => news);
```

I get this warning:

```
[dart] This function has a return type of 'Future<void>', but doesn't end with a return statement. [missing_return]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=> expr` implicitly returns the result of `expr`, so if you want to replace it with a function body `{ return expr; }` you need to add `return`, otherwise `null` will be implicitly returned.

You declared a function with return type `Future<void>` and DartAnalyzer warns you that your function is not returning such a value.

You can either add `async` which makes the function implicitly return a `Future`

```
Future<void> printsome() async {
  final result = await delayedFunction();
}
```

or if you don't want to use `async` you can just add `return`

```
Future<void> printsome() {
  final future = delayedFunction();
  return future.then(print); // return the Future returned by then()
}
```